# Mandrill webhooks, SSL certificate verify failed, verify that the CA cert is OK

Tags: ssl-certificate, mandrill

I've been getting this error for a long while:

**POST to https://www.xxxxxx.com/hook/mandrill/quotations/opened failed: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed**

I got my certificates re-newed by **Comodo** recently & ever since, I've been getting these errors.

It still seems to work though, but I'm worried some of the webhooks might not get through.

Is someone getting these errors as well? Might it be a problem on their side? Cause I have checked my website on https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html and it's seems to be perfectly fine..

Also I'm hosting my website on Amazon

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your installed SSL certificate.  You most likely did not combine the `.crt` file and the `.ca-bundle` file they provided to you and only installed the `.crt` file.  Comodo provides the following two files in the zip package they make available to you:

```
_yourdomain_com.crt

_yourdomain_com.ca-bundle
```

The `.ca-bundle` includes all your intermediate certificates.  You need to combine the contents of the two above files together.  Your output `.crt` file would look something like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
contents of original crt file
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
contents of 1st cert in ca-bundle file
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
contents of 2nd cert in ca-bundle file
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
etc...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

You must list the original certificate as the first certificate in the output file.  Then comes the intermediate certificates in your bundle.

Replace the `.crt` file that your server is pointing to with the above output `.crt` file.  No need to change any of the web server configurations for either Apache or Nginx - both support bundled certificates.  Make sure to restart your web server once the changes are made.

Before you make any of the above changes, you can actually see whether or not the missing `.ca-bundle` is causing your error by running a [SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) against your domain.  In the results section after the test finishes, look for **Additiona Certificates**.  The results will state that you are missing certificates if you do not have the appropriate intermediate certificates in your `.crt` file.